How to make aggregate function value a permanent column value?
I have the following query which gives the current_rating value which I am after. However I am wondering how I then make this query update my table permanently so the current_rating value column permanently has this value.
select *, r.current_rating
from (
    select greydb.*,  array_agg(race_rating) over (
        partition by greyhound
        order by date
        rows between 4 preceding and current row) as rating_5
    from "greydb" ) t
    cross join lateral (
        select avg(r) as current_rating
        from (
            select u.*
            from unnest(t.rating_5) with ordinality u(r, n)
            where r is not null
            order by r desc
            limit 3
            ) r
    ) r


Is it Postgres? Add tag.

Yes. I have added tag now.

Add a separate table for the aggregate values and define a INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE trigger to update it.
